# How to do avoid huge nested if else

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

This is my code for logging in

```
method: 'POST',
        path: '/api/login/sp',
        config: { auth: false },
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            User.findOne({ phone: request.payload.phone }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (user !== null) {
                    user.comparePassword(request.payload.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        if (isMatch) { // Login success
                            data = {
                                "statusCode": 200,
                                "token": generateJWT(user._id)
                            }
                            return reply(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'))
                        }
                    });
                }
                else { // Invalid User
                    reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'))
                }
            });
        }
```

It takes a lot of code and makes it very hard to read. Is there a way to better write this part of the code so that it is easily maintainable and readable?

Comment: this should probably be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here

Comment: Make use of promises.

Comment: Do your async functions return promises? You can avoid arrow structure with `Promise`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: This is [**Callback Hell**](http://callbackhell.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the return early pattern: [Return early pattern for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581710/return-early-pattern-for-functions)

```
User.findOne(..., {
    // generic error
    if (err) throw err;

    // invalid user
    if (user === null) {
        reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'));
        return;
    }

    user.comparePassword(..., {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!isMatch) {
            reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'));
            return;
        }

        data = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "token": generateJWT(user._id)
        };
        reply(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `return reply()`:

```
User.findOne({phone: request.payload.phone}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (user === null) return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'));
    user.comparePassword(request.payload.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!isMatch) return reply(Boom.unauthorized('Invalid Account'));
        data = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "token": generateJWT(user._id)
        };
        return reply(data);
    });
})
```